# Why multi line label is giving error

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

This is my exact tikz code

```
\draw [thick,decoration={brace, mirror,raise=0.55cm},decorate] (BG1-Block2.west) -- (BG1-Block2.east)
       node [pos=0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-0.65cm] {Hello\\World};
```

**Error:**

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                                
l.56 ...0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-0.65cm] {Outer\\Ch};
```

If I remove `\\` I dont get any error. But I need to have a multi line label. Can someone please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error can be reproduced by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {Hello\\World};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The version of `\\`, redefined by the `center` environment, causes the trouble.
But anyway, the node text is still a one-liner. Multi-line node text can be achieved by using option `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[align=center] {Hello\\World};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]